# Get x.getPixelForValue(i) in a chartjs plugin with a time type scale

Tags: chart.js

I have a barchart with chartjs. The x scale is of type: time, data/ticks represented hourly. I wrote a cutom plugin that draws something on canvas. Unfortunately I always get a -32768 for x.getPixelForValue(i), the y.getPixelForValue(i) seems fine.
Am I missed something important or chartjs doesn`t support getPixelForValue on time series bar charts?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I figured out the issue...
The x.getPixelForTick(i) function returns the correct x coordinate for the bars.